# How to find how large a download is for a Steam Game?

Tags: steam

I am considering purchasing a Steam game. I am on a limited download limit, I was wondering how to find out how large a game download is.

I understand I can purchase the game, download a portion and resume at a later date.

The game I am interested in is : [Ace Combat Assault Horizon - Enhanced Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/228400/)

I see there are minimum and recommended settings, however, this does not include the download size of the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible to know this before you actually bought it. 
The download size does also differ greatly from the recommended hard disk space needed, due to all downloads being compressed and how much compression can be applied also differs from game to game. If a game already uses compressed files for their assets, there is not much Steam can do. For example, "The Secret World" is 40.2GB on my HDD and was only 18.5GB in download.

However, the recommended need for hard disk space is a good indicator of the download size. You can often half it. But as I said, it is only an indicator.

Comment: I purchased it and it was half the minimum drive space. thanks.

Comment: aside from a google search which is very hit and miss, this is the easiest without the Steam Client working it out for you.

Answer (score 10):

The third-party Steam database on [steamdb.info](https://steamdb.info/) tracks the download sizes of packages. Visit an application’s page for any game and go to the “Depots” tab. (E.g. for [Ace Combat Assault Horizon](https://steamdb.info/app/228400/depots/) it lists a download size of 11.66 GB.)

As it lists all possible downloads, cross-platform releases will have an overview of the download sizes per platform. Even DLC is shown. A good example of this would be [the depots page for Binding of Isaac: Rebirth](https://steamdb.info/app/250900/depots/).

Comment: Actual link: https://steamdb.info

Comment: Back when I first wrote this answer, I did not have enough rep to include 3 links. I have now added the actual link to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This may seem super obvious, but I honestly forgot about it; hence why I'm adding this answer.

If you already own a game, and you're just trying to figure out whether you have the space for it, you can just go to install it and you'll see this **pre-installation dialogue window** before the download even begins:

[image: Steam Game Pre-Installation Dialogue Window]